# How to use application helper method inside form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, form-for, formbuilder

I want to use a method inside ApplicationHelper in my view inside form_for. This is probably a dumb question, but I could not find help on the Internet how to do this. Here is my code:

views/admin_courses/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @course do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, "User name:" %>
  <%= f.tester("test") %>
<% end %>
```

helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def tester(name)
    test = name + "!"
    test
  end
end
```

So this doesn't work. But if I do `<%= tester("test") %>` then it works. However, I need to do this on `f`. How can I do this? Any help would be appreciated. I feel like I'm not understanding something.

Comment: What do you mean by "However, I need to do this on f"? The tester method doesn't depend on anything from the form... What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Auto complete an input field with the value of "test!"?

Comment: consider `f` an instance of the `Form` object. It responds to its own methods so it could never respond to arbitrary methods you created yourself

Comment: Yes Brad, I am trying to auto complete an input field with the value of "test!".

Comment: PNY, then would I need to use FormBuilder somehow to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to overwrite the default value in a `form_for`, you can set the `value` property.

```
<%= form_for @course do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, "User name:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, value: tester('test') %>
<% end %>
```

This should overwrite the default value (in this case `@course.name`).